# MySQL Update a table based on the last data from another table while grouping with conditions

Tags: mysql, update, subquery, group-by, order-by

**I need a query to UPDATE a series of fields based on another table**

Table **lp_plates_backup**

```
|       uid | brand    | model    |
|         1 |          |          |
|         a | Old      | Error    |
|       ... | ...      | ...      |
```

Table **lp_pictures_backup**

```
| plate_uid | brand    | model    | date_validated      |
|         1 | Fiat     | Panda    | 2014-10-11 10:03:20 | < Last one
|         1 | BMW      | 7-Series | 2014-08-04 11:21:18 |
|         1 | BMW      | 7-Series | 2014-07-28 19:14:02 |
|         1 | Mercedes | S-Class  | 2014-06-12 08:54:57 |
|         a | Tesla    | Model S  | 2014-12-17 11:00:00 | < Last one
|         a | BMW      | 3-Series | 2014-11-07 14:34:11 |
```

I need to update columns **brand** and **model** of **lp_plates_backup** based on the last **date_validated** entry of table **lp_plates_backup** while **lp_plates_backup.uid** match **lp_pictures_backup.plate_uid** for each **lp_plates_backup.uid** but only if:

- **lp_pictures_backup.brand** is not empty
- **lp_plates_backup.brand** is different from **lp_pictures_backup.brand** OR **lp_plates_backup.model** is different from **lp_pictures_backup.model**

The result should shown (**lp_plates_backup**) :

```
|       uid | brand    | model    |
|         1 | Fiat     | Panda    |
|         a | Tesla    | Model S  |
```

I have read these posts and made lot of tests but without getting the expected result:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973246/how-to-specify-the-parent-query-field-from-within-a-subquery-in-mysql
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038193/select-row-with-most-recent-date-per-user
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156163/optimize-sub-query-selecting-last-record-of-each-group

Here is the last query I try:

```
UPDATE
    lp_plates_backup AS t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            plate_uid, brand, model, date_validated
        FROM
            lp_pictures_backup as parent
        WHERE
            brand <> '' AND
            date_validated = (SELECT MAX(date_validated)
                 FROM lp_pictures_backup as t2
                 WHERE t2.plate_uid = parent.plate_uid)
        GROUP BY
            plate_uid
    ORDER BY
        date_validated DESC

) AS m ON
    m.plate_uid = t.uid
SET
    t.brand = m.brand,
    t.model = m.model
WHERE
    t.brand <> m.brand
    OR
    t.model <> m.model
```

I think I had too much brainstormed and getting confused making useless too complicated code.

Any expert in the place?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Reading the query, I think  `LEFT JOIN` must be replaced with `INNER JOIN`.  
You can get rid of `ORDER BY date_validated DESC` because you don't need to order subquery result.

Comment: `group by plate_uid` must be placed into subquery starting with `SELECT MAX(date_validated)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct query is:

```
UPDATE
    lp_plates_backup AS t
    INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT
            plate_uid, brand, model, date_validated
        FROM
            lp_pictures_backup as parent
        WHERE
            brand <> '' AND
            date_validated = (
                 SELECT MAX(date_validated)
                 FROM lp_pictures_backup as t2
                 WHERE t2.plate_uid = parent.plate_uid
                 GROUP BY
                     plate_uid)
) AS m ON
    m.plate_uid = t.uid
SET
    t.brand = m.brand,
    t.model = m.model
WHERE
    t.brand <> m.brand
    OR
    t.model <> m.model;
```

Just some little explanations. You need `INNER JOIN` because you must update row of `lp_plates_backup` only if `plate_uid` exists into `lp_plates_backup`. `ORDER BY` is useless because you are selecting all rows, order is not important.

You need the max `date_validated` of rows grouped by `plate_uid`, select MAX(date_validate) must individuate only a row for `plate_uid` through the `date_validated` field. So you need to add group by to select max(..).

The query `select plate_uid` returns a row for `plate_uid` so you don't need to aggregate here. The condition of single row is already builded into `select max` subquery.

I hope you did not get confused by me :-)

---

**Updated**

The previous works well if `date_validate` is the pair (`plate_uid`, `date_validated`) is unique.
If you have this kind of data:

```
| plate_uid | brand    | model    | date_validated      |
|         1 | Fiat     | Panda    | 2014-10-11 10:03:20 | 
|         1 | BMW      | 7-Series | 2014-10-11 10:03:20 |   <- changed data
|         1 | BMW      | 7-Series | 2014-07-28 19:14:02 |
|         1 | Mercedes | S-Class  | 2014-06-12 08:54:57 |   
|         a | Tesla    | Model S  | 2014-12-17 11:00:00 | 
|         a | BMW      | 3-Series | 2014-11-07 14:34:11 |
```

The following query returns the first two rows for `plate_uid` 1.

```
SELECT plate_uid, brand, model, date_validated
FROM lp_pictures_backup as parent
WHERE
      brand <> '' AND
      date_validated = (
                 SELECT MAX(date_validated)
                 FROM lp_pictures_backup as t2
                 WHERE t2.plate_uid = parent.plate_uid
                 GROUP BY plate_uid)
```

The update will choice the values from the first or the second row. I think of the following alternatives:

1. using some other `lp_pictures_backup` fields to choise between rows with the same date_validated.
2. enforcing a unique constraint on table. I.e. `alter table lp_pictures_backup add unique index (plate_id, date_validated)`. Rejecting invalid data.
3. detecting valid `lp_pictures_backup` pair of `(plate_uid, date_validated)`. Updating `lp_plates_backup` only with valid pairs, review invalid pairs and correct them.

Maybe there are more alternatives. I prefer enforcing contraint on data so to have better data. I expand 3th alternative. Just create a view to define what a valid pair `(plate_uid, date_validated)` is:

```
CREATE VIEW lp_pictures_backup_valid as
SELECT plate_uid, date_validated
FROM lp_pictures_backup as parent
WHERE date_validated = (
        select max(date_validated) 
        from lp_pictures_backup t2 
        where t2.plate_uid =  parent.plate_uid GROUP BY plate_uid
      )
group by plate_uid, date_validated
having count(*) = 1;                    <-- you can change this to make an invalid row
```

A valid pair `(plate_uid, date_validated)` is a pair with the max date_validated only if there are a unique date_validated value.

I rewrite the update statements to consider only valid pair:

```
UPDATE
    lp_plates_backup AS t
    INNER JOIN  (
        -- modification start
        SELECT p.plate_uid, p.brand, p.model, p.date_validated
        FROM lp_pictures_backup as p
             INNER JOIN lp_pictures_backup_valid valid 
                        ON p.plate_uid = valid.plate_uid and 
                           p.date_validated = valid.date_validated
        WHERE p.brand <> '')
        -- modification end
    ) 
    AS m ON m.plate_uid = t.uid
SET
    t.brand = m.brand,
    t.model = m.model
WHERE
    t.brand <> m.brand
    OR
    t.model <> m.model;
```

Hope this make sense.

---

Update: 2014-03-20

In the first case:

> Blockquote
>    1. using some other `lp_pictures_backup` fields to choise between rows with the same date_validated.

I have assumed your date is like this:

```
|id| plate_uid | brand    | model    | date_validated      |
|4 |         1 | Fiat     | Panda    | 2014-10-11 10:03:20 | 
|3 |         1 | BMW      | 7-Series | 2014-10-11 10:03:20 |   
|2 |         1 | BMW      | 7-Series | 2014-07-28 19:14:02 |
|1 |         1 | Mercedes | S-Class  | 2014-06-12 08:54:57 |    
|2 |         a | Tesla    | Model S  | 2014-12-17 11:00:00 | 
|1 |         a | BMW      | 3-Series | 2014-11-07 14:34:11 |
```

You can try this:

```
UPDATE
    lp_plates_backup AS t
    INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT t1.plate_uid, t1.brand, t1.model, t1.date_validated
        FROM lp_pictures_backup as t1,
          (SELECT t2.plate_uid, MAX(id) as id,  MAX(date_validated) as dv
           FROM lp_pictures_backup as t2
           GROUP BY t2.plate_uid) as t3                 
        WHERE t1.brand <> '' AND
              t1.plate_uid = t3.plate_uid AND
              t1.date_validated = t3.dv AND
              t1.id = t3.id
) AS m ON
    m.plate_uid = t.uid
SET
    t.brand = m.brand,
    t.model = m.model
WHERE
    t.brand <> m.brand
    OR
    t.model <> m.model;
```

The fields used to choise the row to be updated are extracted by this part:

```
 ...
 (SELECT t2.plate_uid, MAX(id) as id,  MAX(date_validated) as dv
  FROM lp_pictures_backup as t2
  GROUP BY t2.plate_uid) as t3 
 ...
```

So it assumes a correlation between date_validated and id: at increasing dates corresponds to increasing id.

Hope it help.

Comment: Thank you first for your quick reaction and professionel advices.

To be more clear: `plate_uid` exists for sure into `lp_plates_backup`. Does it change something at your code?

Comment: Using this query, I compare old and new data:

Comment: For your first comment. It doesn't change my code.

Comment: After running the above query, i still get some difference. Maybe due to the fact that some lines have exactly the same `date_validated` value? How to manage that and only take the first result?

Comment: If you have two (or more rows) with the same `date_validated` for `plate_uid` more rows will be extracted, you will get two (or more update) for the same `lp_plates_backup.uid`. I will goes to update my aswer.

Comment: Thank again for such detailed precision. There is a `id` field in `lp_pictures_backup` that is incremented on a per `plate_uid` basis. How can this field `id` be used to get the last validated as the first alternative you suggest in the update query (`MAX(lp_pictures_backup.id)`) ?

Comment: You are welcome. I have added  something to my reply.